# aligning form in nav menu

Tags: html, css

[image: It align now][image]CSS: This suppose to be at the left of the first navigation which is the clothing

```
#nav {
width:95%;
font-family: Tahoma;
font: bold;
color: #00FFFF;
float: none;
  }
.form{
    height:50px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:Candara;
    color:#00FFFF;
    background-color: transparent;
    min-width: 160px;
    float:left-wards;


}
.dropbtn {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #00FFFF;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index:1000;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: #00FFFF;
    padding: 6px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    z-index:1000;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: transparent}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    z-index:1000;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

NAV MENU: This is the main nav menu suppose to be the radio male or female should be inline with the navigation but its not the case here

```
<nav>
    <div id="nav" align="center">
        <div style="display:inline-block">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <form class="form">
            <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male"> Male
            <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female"> Female
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class = "dropdown" width = "10">
            <div class = "dropdown" width = "10">

            <button class="dropbtn">Clothing</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a id="formal" href="#formal">Formal</a></br>
                                <a id="maleFormal" style="display:none" href="formalM.html">Male Formal</a>
                                <a id="femaleFormal" style="display:none" href="formalF.html">Female Formal</a>
                        <a id="shirt" href="#shirt">Shirt</a></br>
                                <a id="maleShirt" style="display:none" href="shirtM.html">Male Shirt</a>
                                <a id="femaleShirt" style="display:none" href="shirtF.html">Female Shirt</a>
                        <a id="jeans" href="#jeans">Jeans</a></br>
                                <a id="maleJeans" style="display:none" href="jeansM.html">Pants</a>
                                <a id="femaleJeans" style="display:none" href="jeansF.html">Jeans</a>
                        <a id="shortandskirt" href="#shortandskirt">Short and Skirt</a></br>
                                <a id="maleshortandskirt" style="display:none" href="shorts.html">Shorts</a>
                                <a id="femaleshortandskirt" style="display:none" href="skirts.html">Skirts</a>
                    </div>  
            </div>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#male").click(function(){
                        $("#formal").hide();
                        $("#maleFormal").show();
                        $("#femaleFormal").hide();
                    });
                    $("#female").click(function(){ 
                        $("#formal").hide();
                        $("#maleFormal").hide();
                        $("#femaleFormal").show();
                    });
                });
            </script>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#male").click(function(){
                        $("#shirt").hide();
                        $("#maleShirt").show();
                        $("#femaleShirt").hide();
                    });
                    $("#female").click(function(){ 
                        $("#shirt").hide();
                        $("#maleShirt").hide();
                        $("#femaleShirt").show();
                    });
                });
            </script>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#male").click(function(){
                        $("#jeans").hide();
                        $("#maleJeans").show();
                        $("#femaleJeans").hide();
                    });
                    $("#female").click(function(){ 
                        $("#jeans").hide();
                        $("#maleJeans").hide();
                        $("#femaleJeans").show();
                    });
                });
            </script>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#male").click(function(){
                        $("#shortandskirt").hide();
                        $("#maleshortandskirt").show();
                        $("#femaleshortandskirt").hide();
                    });
                    $("#female").click(function(){ 
                        $("#shortandskirt").hide();
                        $("#maleshortandskirt").hide();
                        $("#femaleshortandskirt").show();
                    });
                });
            </script>

        </div>
        <div class = "dropdown" width = "10">
            <button class="dropbtn">Accesory</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#ring">Ring</a></br>
                        <a href="#necklace">Necklace</a></br>
                        <a href="#pendant">Pendant</a></br>
                        <a href="#bracelet">Bracelet</a></br>
                        <a href="#eye glasses">Eye Glasses</a></br>
                        <a href="#sun glasses">Sun Glasses</a></br>
                        <a href="#fashion glasses">Fashion Glasses</a></br>
                    </div>  
        </div>
        <div class = "dropdown" width = "10">
            <button class="dropbtn">Shoe</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#rubber shoes">Rubber Shoes</a></br>
                        <a href="#running shoe">Running Shoe</a></br>
                        <a href="#formal shoe">Formal Shoe</a></br>
                        <a href="#flat shoes">Flat Shoes</a></br>
                        <a href="#high heels">High Heels</a></br>
                        <a href="#sandals">Sandals</a></br>
                    </div>  
        </div>
        <div class = "dropdown" width = "10">
            <button class="dropbtn">Bags</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#sling bags">Sling bags</a></br>
                        <a href="#backpack">Backpack</a></br>
                        <a href="#office Bags">Office Bags</a></br>
                        <a href="#fahion bags">Fashion bags</a></br>
                        <a href="#gym bag">Gym Bag</a></br>
                    </div>  
        </div>
        <div class = "dropdown" width = "10">
            <button class="dropbtn">Watches</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#rolex">Rolex</a></br>
                        <a href="#swatch">Swatch</a></br>
                        <a href="#timex">Timex</a></br>
                    </div>  

        </div>
        <div class = "dropdown" width = "10">
            <button class="dropbtn">Kids</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#clothing">Clothing</a></br>
                        <a href="#accesory">Accesory</a></br>
                        <a href="#shoe">Shoe</a></br>
                        <a href="#bags">Bags</a></br>
                        <a href="#watch">Watch</a></br>
                    </div>  
        </div>
        <div class = "dropdown" width = "10">
            <button class="dropbtn">Toys</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#cars">Cars</a></br>
                        <a href="#guns">Guns</a></br>
                        <a href="#kitchen sets">kitchen sets</a></br>
                        <a href="#doll">Doll</a></br>
                        <a href="#doll house">Doll House</a></br>
                        <a href="#stuff toys">Stuff Toy</a></br>
                    </div>  
        </div>
        <div class = "dropdown" width = "10">
            <button class="dropbtn">Unisex</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#clothing">Clothing</a></br>
                        <a href="#accesory">Accesory</a></br>
                        <a href="#shoe">Shoe</a></br>
                        <a href="#bags">Bags</a></br>
                        <a href="#watch">Watch</a></br>
                    </div>  
        </div>
        <div class = "dropdown" width = "10">
            <button class="dropbtn">Brands</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#nike">Nike</a></br>
                        <a href="#guess">Guess</a></br>
                        <a href="#humane">Humane</a></br>
                        <a href="#prada">Prada</a></br>
                        <a href="#LV">LV</a></br>
                    </div>  
        </div>
        <div class = "dropdown" width = "10">
            <button class="dropbtn">Deals</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#50% discounts">50% Discounts</a></br>
                        <a href="#60% discounts">60% Discounts</a></br>
                        <a href="#70% discounts">70% Discounts</a></br>
                        <a href="#free shipping">Free Shipping</a></br>
                        <a href="#coupons">Coupons</a></br>
                    </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This is the result 
[image: Nav menu]

Comment: Please elaborate your question more and if possible provide working snippet

Comment: snippit already attach -- radio male or female should be beside Clothing

Comment: Add display:inline-block in div outside form instead of form. may be this will work for you.

Comment: We need proper code to debug or solve you problem.

Comment: your html is different from your image and also you have not attached all the css.

Comment: CSS HTM AND JS already attached -  I didn't attached all of the code coz its too long what I only wants is to postion form and navigation. I thought attaching it would be useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to remove padding from button and it will work fine.`padding: 16px;` remove from button.

```css
#nav {
  width: 95%;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font: bold;
  color: #00FFFF;
  float: none;
}
.form {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Candara;
  color: #00FFFF;
  background-color: transparent;
  min-width: 160px;
  float: leftwards;
}
.dropbtn {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #00FFFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1000;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #00FFFF;
  padding: 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: transparent
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="nav" align="center">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <form class="form">
      <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">Male
      <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">Female
    </form>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Accesory</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#ring">Ring</a>
          <a href="#necklace">Necklace</a>
          <a href="#pendant">Pendant</a>
          <a href="#bracelet">Bracelet</a>
          <a href="#eye glasses">Eye Glasses</a>
          <a href="#sun glasses">Sun Glasses</a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="dropdown" width="10">
        <button class="dropbtn">Shoe</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#rubber shoes">Rubber Shoes</a>
          </br>
          <a href="#running shoe">Running Shoe</a>
          </br>
          <a href="#formal shoe">Formal Shoe</a>
          </br>
          <a href="#flat shoes">Flat Shoes</a>
          </br>
          <a href="#high heels">High Heels</a>
          </br>
          <a href="#sandals">Sandals</a>
          </br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use following CSS to resolve your problem:

```
#nav > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to put it in left of the Clothing button